# How to avoid PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice, GOTREF / DECREF Python API calls?

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I have a problem with cythonizing my code, more specifically the following (and similar) sniplets:

```
cdef double [:,:] grad_d_him_d_jm
grad_d_ihm_d_jm = grad_d_im_d_jm(...)
```

where grad_d_im_d_jm(...) would return a double [:,:] memoryview.
This code would be translated by Cython into the following C code:

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_24gradient_better_c_mviews_grad_d_im_d_jm(__pyx_v_i, __pyx_v_j, __pyx_v_m, __pyx_v_structure, __pyx_v_distances); 
if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 203;  __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
__pyx_t_7 = __Pyx_PyObject_to_MemoryviewSlice_dsds_double(__pyx_t_1);
if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7.memview)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 203; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
__pyx_v_grad_d_ihm_d_jm = __pyx_t_7;
__pyx_t_7.memview = NULL;
__pyx_t_7.data = NULL;
```

As I'm doing this in loops, I suspect the Python API calls to have quite some impact on the speed of my code.

the GOTREF / DECREF call occurs also on other occasions, along with a PyFloat_asFloat:

```
cdef float sp
sp = scalar_product()
```

where scalar_product() returns a cdef float. This snippet gets translated to

```
__pyx_t_1 = __pyx_f_24gradient_better_c_mviews_scalar_product(__pyx_v_i, __pyx_v_j, __pyx_v_m, __pyx_v_structure); 
if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_1)) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 178; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
__Pyx_GOTREF(__pyx_t_1);
__pyx_t_2 = __pyx_PyFloat_AsFloat(__pyx_t_1); 
if (unlikely((__pyx_t_2 == (float)-1) && PyErr_Occurred())) {__pyx_filename = __pyx_f[0]; __pyx_lineno = 178; __pyx_clineno = __LINE__; goto __pyx_L1_error;}
__Pyx_DECREF(__pyx_t_1); __pyx_t_1 = 0;
__pyx_v_sp = __pyx_t_2;
```

I am running Python 2.7.11+ and Cython 0.23.4. I would be very grateful if you could either tell me that a) this is not relevant for performance or b) how to fix it.
Let me know if I can improve the question, I'd be happy to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These appear to be part of Cython reference counting API explained [here](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/enhancements-refnanny).

My guess is that `grad_d_im_d_jm` returns a Python object (e.g. NumPy array) and thus Cython has to decrement the object reference counter after the memoryview was obtained.

As for `scalar_product`, I think it is either a def (rather than cdef) or is untyped. For example the following

```
cdef g():
    return 1.0
```

compiles to

```
// ...
__Pyx_XDECREF(__pyx_r);
__Pyx_INCREF(__pyx_float_1_0);
__pyx_r = __pyx_float_1_0;
goto __pyx_L0;
```

However, once you specify the return type the refcounting calls are gone

```
cdef float g():
    return 1.0
```

becomes

```
// ...
__pyx_r = 1.0;
goto __pyx_L0;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! scalar_product is a cdef and its returned value is a cdef'ed float. Same goes for grad_d_im_d_jm; only that the returned value is a cdef'ed float-typed 2D memoryview. Actually, when printing type(grad_d_im_d_jm) it says it's a memoryviewslice. What I do in grad_d_im_d_jm() is initializing a memoryview with mv=numpy.zeros((n,n)) and then adding stuff to single elements. I looked into the refnanny thing, but could not yet find a way to turn it off (only as an option for runtests.py). Would you happen to know one?

Comment: Nanny is only used to debug Cython itself. E.g. the generated C file has an ifdef replacing `__Pyx_DECREF` with `Py_DECREF` unless the user specifically set `-DCYTHON_REFNANY`.

Comment: Is it possible to share the relevant code? I cannot reproduce the issue locally with stub functions.

Comment: I feel it's time for me to be embarrassed. I so far mainly cythonized single functions as (cp)defs, but in my code I call a lot of cdef'ed functions. I actually didn't think of specifying the return type in the function header! I didn't read your answer carefully enough, else I would have noticed immediately. So sorry for that! Interesting, though, that specifying the return types only results in a speedup of about 15%. In any case, thanks so much! Your answer is of course correct - I was just thinking I had the return type specified with cdef'ing the returned variable in the function body.